# In Linux, how can I temporarily remove my association with a group?

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts

I need to test linux group permissions on a repository.  In one shell, how can I temporarily remove one of my group associations?

e.g.
If my groups are defined as:

```
 % groups
 foo bar baz
```

How can I make it so it only returns `foo bar` without `baz`?

Comment: In a comment, you mentioned you don't have root permissions, but it may be useful for those who do to take a look at gpasswd, newgrp, and possibly also /etc/sudoers for hints at implementing something. I'm currently looking into authorizing users to remove themselves from groups they're already in, but I'm more trying to do the opposite(temporarily add myself to groups so sensitive information is inaccessible until I want it) which may be easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It IS possible.

Check out [this code](http://pastebin.com/f22bf098e) (valid C89, heh) I wrote in 25 mins. Usage example:

```
whitequark@forth:~/skipgroup$ ls
skipgroup.c
whitequark@forth:~/skipgroup$ gcc skipgroup.c -o skipgroup
whitequark@forth:~/skipgroup$ sudo chown root:root skipgroup
whitequark@forth:~/skipgroup$ sudo chmod u+s skipgroup
whitequark@forth:~/skipgroup$ groups
whitequark adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
whitequark@forth:~/skipgroup$ ./skipgroup 
Usage: ./skipgroup <group to remove>
Must be SUID. Launches shell.
whitequark@forth:~/skipgroup$ ./skipgroup cdrom
$ id
uid=1000(whitequark) gid=1000(whitequark)
groups=4(adm),20(dialout),46(plugdev),104(lpadmin),114(admin),118(sambashare),1000(whitequark)
```

**WARNING** THIS CODE IS SUID!

While it drops privileges as you see on id's output, it MAY BE DANGEROUS. Dixi.

Comment: wow.  If I had root permissions, I'd definitely try this out.

Comment: I think there is really no way to change your group list without root privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is not possible, since files (and POSIX ACLs) can specify subtractive rights for certain groups.  Allowing people to escape from a group would then be a security hole.

Of course if you have root access, you could simply remove yourself from the  group and do

```
sudo su - $USER
```